# --force-yes required to install heroku toolbelt?

Tags: ubuntu, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I've installed heroku toolbelt on many different platforms to date, and was surprised to find myself having trouble doing it on ubuntu 12.04.  Some of the issues I encountered are explained, I think by some other StackOverflow posts, namely "sh" not running anything, but it seems odd that the --force-yes should be required and that it is absent from Heroku's script - I have also posted a ticket with Heroku themselves.

Running the command specified lead to no apparent activity:

`saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ wget -qo-  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$`

By playing around I was ultimately able to grab the script:

`saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ wget --no-check-certificate http://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
--2013-10-10 12:50:32--  http://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com... 174.129.17.173, 54.243.76.97, 23.21.198.2
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com|174.129.17.173|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh [following]
--2013-10-10 12:50:33--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com|174.129.17.173|:443... connected.
WARNING: certificate common name`www.heroku.com' doesn't match requested host name `toolbelt.heroku.com'.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 572 [text/plain]
Saving to:`install-ubuntu.sh.1'

100%[======================================>] 572         --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-10-10 12:50:33 (60.1 MB/s) - `install-ubuntu.sh.1' saved [572/572]`

However nothing ran.  I ran the script directly:

`saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ ./install-ubuntu.sh 
This script requires superuser access to install apt packages.
You will be prompted for your password by sudo.
[sudo] password for saasbook: 
--2013-10-10 12:52:14--  https://toolbelt.heroku.com/apt/release.key
Resolving toolbelt.heroku.com... 174.129.17.173, 54.243.76.97, 23.21.198.2
Connecting to toolbelt.heroku.com|174.129.17.173|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name`www.heroku.com' doesn't match requested host name 'toolbelt.heroku.com'.
To connect to toolbelt.heroku.com insecurely, use '--no-check-certificate'.
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric Release
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Get:1 http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg [72 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric Release
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Sources
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric InRelease
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe TranslationIndex
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/main Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com oneiric/universe Translation-en
Get:2 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg [490 B]
Get:3 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release [1,673 B]
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release
Get:4 http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages [1,041 B]
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
Fetched 3,276 B in 8s (367 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C927EBE00F1B0520
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,844 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ heroku login
heroku: command not found`

but there were problems about the lack of --force-yes

I was finally able to install by running this additional command:

`saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ sudo apt-get install -y heroku-toolbelt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,844 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ which heroku
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes heroku-toolbelt
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
Suggested packages:
  ruby1.9.1-examples ri1.9.1 ruby1.9.1-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt libreadline5 libruby1.9.1 ruby1.9.1
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,844 kB of archives.
After this operation, 15.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  foreman heroku heroku-toolbelt
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libreadline5 i386 5.2-9ubuntu1 [123 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe libruby1.9.1 i386 1.9.2.290-2 [3,929 kB]
Get:3 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ foreman 0.60.0 [89.5 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/universe ruby1.9.1 i386 1.9.2.290-2 [36.5 kB]
Get:5 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ heroku 3.0.0 [665 kB]
Get:6 http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu/ ./ heroku-toolbelt 3.0.0 [626 B]
Fetched 4,844 kB in 4s (997 kB/s)

Selecting previously deselected package libreadline5.
(Reading database ... 134658 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libreadline5 (from .../libreadline5_5.2-9ubuntu1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package libruby1.9.1.
Unpacking libruby1.9.1 (from .../libruby1.9.1_1.9.2.290-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package ruby1.9.1.
Unpacking ruby1.9.1 (from .../ruby1.9.1_1.9.2.290-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package foreman.
Unpacking foreman (from .../foreman_0.60.0_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package heroku.
Unpacking heroku (from .../archives/heroku_3.0.0_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package heroku-toolbelt.
Unpacking heroku-toolbelt (from .../heroku-toolbelt_3.0.0_all.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up libreadline5 (5.2-9ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libruby1.9.1 (1.9.2.290-2) ...
Setting up ruby1.9.1 (1.9.2.290-2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/gem1.9.1 to provide /usr/bin/gem (gem) in auto mode.
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 to provide /usr/bin/ruby (ruby) in auto mode.
Setting up foreman (0.60.0) ...
Setting up heroku (3.0.0) ...
Setting up heroku-toolbelt (3.0.0) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/Github/ruby-sample$ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.`

I assume there is something odd about my setup, because this has always gone very smoothly in the past.  Is there perhaps some simple change to my system or the script that would help others avoid this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the exactly same issue. I made a guess and tried installing it with sudo and it worked !!

Use this instead:

```
sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: This allso did not help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and i fixed it by commenting heroku related lines in /etc/apt/sources.list  and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/heroku.list

Then i re-ran the script again, and it worked :

```
sudo wget -qO- https://toolbelt.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

This seems to happen if you have the following configured at same time in your software sources files :

```
deb http://toolbelt.heroku.com/ubuntu ./
```

AND :

```
deb https://cli-assets.heroku.com/branches/stable/apt ./
```